# Compare two tables (same structure and data) between two different database (Oracle vs SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, oracle, checksum

Any suggestions on how to compare two tables stored in different databases having exactly same structure and data.

Oracle supports `DBMS_SQLHASH.GETHASH`:

```
SELECT DBMS_SQLHASH.GETHASH('SELECT <Field1> FROM <TABLE1> order by <FIELD1>', 2) AS hash_value 
FROM DUAL
```

where `Field1` is the primary key.

Microsoft SQL Server supports `CHECKSUM` table. Attempts to create a MD5 hash requires it to be converted into string which would generate a different value as Oracle takes the query as input

```
HASHBYTES('MD5', 
 SELECT Field1 
  FROM table1.field1
  order by field1
  FOR XML RAW ))
```

Comment: MySQL isn't from Microsoft. Do you mean SQL-Server?

Comment: MySQL is a database engine owned by Oracle Corp.  SQL Server is a database engine owned by Microsoft.  There is no such thing as "Microsoft MYSQL".  Which dataabase are you actually using?  My guess is Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Yes.. you spotted it before i managed to correct it :).. we are using Oracle and Mircrosoft..

Comment: How often does this need to happen?  How much data?  How quickly does the comparison need to happen?  The cheap option is to create a database link in Oracle pointing to SQL Server or a linked server in SQL Server pointing to Oracle and run a query that just compares the data in the tables.  But that obviously requires moving all the data over the network which doesn't scale very well.  Trying to use a built-in hash in general falls down because it is likely that there are differences in how things like dates are hashed (binary representations differ).

Comment: The `dbms_crypto` package in Oracle implements most any hash you'd care to pick, including MD5 https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_crypto.htm#ARPLS664  You'd need to figure out how to pass in the same string that the SQL Server query returns using a bit of XQuery.

Comment: Thanks Justin.. before we even to move to things like dates..

Comment: Thanks Justin... we started with the primary key ( char10) to ensure the queries do match.. however the XML to string in Microsoft does not seem to work..

Comment: _"however the XML to string in Microsoft does not seem to work."_ It works just fine, but you're assuming `FOR XML RAW` generates exactly the same XML that Oracle would and that it uses the same UCS-2 encoding. How do you know `DBMS_SQLHASH.GETHASH()` even generates XML internally?